# How to convert line breaks in input form in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

How do you usually convert line breaks in a form textbox or input=text element to html line breaks?

Thanks

Edit: Is it always \r\n with all browsers?

Comment: How do you get a line break in a text field?  Or are you meaning a TextArea?

Answer (score 6):

Or in C#:

```
myString.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
```

If you're worried about it being different on different platforms, you could also do:

```
myString.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
myString.Replace("\n", "<br />");
myString.Replace("\r", "<br />");
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is it always \r\n with all browsers?

This is handled on the server, it has nothing to do with browser. However I would suggest using:

```
System.Environment.NewLine
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Replace(vbcrlf, "<br />")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace(urString, "\r?\n", "< br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scenario this could also work:

```
MyString.Replace(Chr(10), "<br/>")
```

Answer (score -1):

You will most likely have to escape the back slashes for it to behave the way you are expecting.

```
MyString.Replace("\\r\\n", "<br />")
```

or

```
MyString.Replace("\\r\\n", Environment.NewLine)
```